# How to automatically backup everything to a safe location

Tags: backup

I would like to discuss the best way(s) to **automatically** backup **all data** on a phone including system, data and sdcard to a server or computer. This should be **scheduled** so that one will loose as little data as possible if the phone or tablet gets lost/stolen.

I don't want to exclude Googles Backup system totally but I personally look for a different solution because I don't want to hand over my data to any cloud service, so if the best way would be the cloud it had to be **encrypted**.

Incremental Backups would be great but I don't see that happening.

My devices are all rooted, otherwise a system backup wouldn't be possible of course.

Tools that come to mind and their respective disadvantages:

- Clockworkmod Recovery / TWRP > *cannot be automated*
- Online Nandroid Backup > *would fill up the SDcard because incremental is not supported*
- Bittorrent Sync > *can only sync folders not the whole sdcard (what about App2SD partition?)*
- Rsync > *only works for SDcard and hard to automate (on Windows)*
- Airdroid > *only for SDCard*
- Titanium Backup > *no SDcard backup, only selected data backup*

**What kind of backup system would you suggest?**

Comment: [This](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79605/backup-all-android-files-to-pc) looks a little like a duplicate but he is looking for a one time solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest Titanium Backup - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup, since I haven't really tried any other apps.

I used to use it when I first got Android after I rooted, I used that to do a backup before installing a new ROM. Was incredible. Don't know about the scheduling though, but that wouldn't surprise me if it had it.

Comment: It is a great tool indeed (forgot that one in my list) but does it backuo sdcard as well?

Comment: I can't lie to you, I honestly don't remember... I never backed up the card because I had the card when I did a ROM install. Get the demo

Comment: I have the pro version and TB does not backup SD, how would it?

Comment: @sir_brickalot, If I may ask, what content are you looking to backup? What is on your SD card? Reason I ask is because if it is photos and videos, I have mine automatically backup to the cloud. Was just thinking that maybe there is a solution if you adjust your thoughts around "What do I need to back up?" instead of "How to backup everything?"

Comment: Thanks, the reason I want to backup everything is because of things I did NOT think of! I.e. : Did I backup my private key for Threema to SDcard or maybe a textfile somewhere, or an encfs container.