# Back up whole system via ssh

Tags: backup

How can I back up my complete android system (settings, apps *and* data)

- to my own network storage (preferably via `ssh` or `rsync`),
- in a way that allows reasonably quick recovery of the whole system (e.g. after I replaced the hardware),
- but also allows me to restore individual apps, including the app’s data,
- ideally in a form that allows incremental backups (`rsync`, `borg`)

A rooted phone can be assumed, if necessary.

Comment: I recently moved to Android from Sailfish OS, where I could just use the same `rsync`-based backup as with all my other Linux devices, and I miss that convenience.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84390/how-to-automatically-backup-everything-to-a-safe-location
(I was unable to find that with Google, but StackExchange’s suggestion of related questions helps…)

Comment: Afraid that's not as easy as you think. There are [rsync apps for Android](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync#group_169), but you'd not only need root to get the files off your device, but the hardware to *fully* restore on must be identical. "Whole system" I'd not do based on that.

Comment: What about this “nandroid” backup thing – isn't that whole system? Is there an easy work-flow around that?

Comment: Sure there is. But again: A Nandroid backup should only be restored to identical hardware. For details, might I suggest you take a look at our fine [backup tag-wiki](/tags/backup/info) – and the [nandroid tag-wiki](/tags/nandroid/info)?

Comment: Trying hard to avoid chatting here … but thanks for the links. They led me to http://en.miui.com/thread-327449-1-1.html which indicates that from a nandroid backup, I can also recover individual apps, if needed. So if TWRP backup over nand [would work as advertised](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/877#issuecomment-403293758) then I’d be set :-)

Comment: Don't forget to answer your own question with the set-up you end up choosing.